# Film of human versus alien

Tags: story-identification, movie

It was a long time ago, so I remember only some particular.

The alien was something like an insect, and they were greater than human. The human was taking a bomb to the alien's home planet (I think), but somehow the alien get into the human ship and I remember the ending scene:

> one man has a bionic eye, and looks for targeting the enemy world on a rod-like connection, but one of the man was a particularly small alien, and kills him pushing its head in the rod. The other man manage to pull the trigger, but in the end the alien wins, as the earth was on target

Comment: Duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate; http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/18962/movie-name-where-in-the-end-the-earth-spaceship-ends-up-shooting-earth-itself-af/18969#18969, http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39278/movie-or-tv-film-full-story-happen-on-a-military-starship-which-goes-to-desto/39279#39279, http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/39278/movie-or-tv-film-full-story-happen-on-a-military-starship-which-goes-to-desto/39280#39280

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're describing the Outer Limits episode ["The Light Brigade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Light_Brigade_%28The_Outer_Limits%29)" starring Robert Patrick:

> The Light Brigade's purpose is to deliver this powerful weapon to
>   destroy the enemy homeworld. Unfortunately the aliens ambush the ship,
>   and use their unique methods to trick the survivors of the Light
>   Brigade into failing their mission. This feat is achieved by Robert
>   Patrick's character, John Skokes, whose physical likeness has been
>   assumed by an alien spy, meaning the real Skokes never escaped
>   captivity.
>
> In the closing scene, at huge personal cost, the bomb is released over
>   what the crew believe to be the alien homeworld. It is in fact Earth,
>   and the mission is not only a failure, but the unleashing of the
>   doomsday weapon on an already crippled humanity.

[image]

If you're in the US, you can watch it online [here](http://video.app.msn.com/watch/video/the-light-brigade/17wuvkx8q?cpkey=e94e1cd8-9f50-43fe-b4c9-5254abf96d9d%257c%257c%257c%257c)